# Does Sublime Text have support for Ruby API (auto-complete)?

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, sublimetext2, sublimetext

How can I get the list of methods that are available for some object or class, like this:

[image: Netbeans auto-complete]

Does Sublime Text have this feature for Ruby?
just like this https://github.com/BoundInCode/Display-Functions , but for Ruby

NOTE: i don't talk about tab complete, what i want for example if i typed "Array." then a list of the Array class methods ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html show up in a list, just like in netbeans with java or in eclipse

Comment: Have you searched using your favorite search engine?  If not, here is a good start...https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tab+completion+for+ruby+in+sublime+text+2 with this following link as a good reference:
 http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/06/21/sublime-text-2-for-ruby/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 has some degree of auto-complete functionality right out of the box. If you want to kick it up a notch, the [Sublime CodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel) plugin is probably the closest thing to intelli-sense that we have for Sublime Text w/ Ruby, supporting:

> - Jump to Symbol Definition - Jump to the file and line of the    definition of a symbol.
> - Imports autocomplete - Shows autocomplete    with the available modules/symbols in real time.
> - Function Call    tooltips - Displays information in the status bar about the working    function.

---

**Auto-complete**:

[image: sample auto-complete / intelli-sense]

---

**Symbol definition**:

[image: sample symbol definition]

Would output the following to the status bar:

> Info: Passes each element of
>   the collection to the given block. The method returns true if the
>   block ever returns a value other than false or nil. If the block is
>   not given, Ruby adds an implicit block of { |obj| obj } that will
>   cause any? to return true if at least one of the collection members is
>   not false or nil.

---

**If you run into install/usage issues:**

At the time of posting this answer, I couldn't get the tool-tips to work and the auto-complete doesn't support external gems, and I also had some issues with installing via package installer. If you run into issues installing try manually cloning the repo into your packages folder. For me this was located at `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/`.

If you successfully install and are still having issues getting it running at that point, try re-building as mentioned in the plugin's read-me. Also check out the fix mentioned here:

https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel/issues/249#issuecomment-19763941

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this isn't what i want, i want for example if i typed "Array." then a list of the Array class methods  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html show up in a list

Comment: @Marwan - There are nearly 100 Array methods - why would you want a list that large to pop up every time you began to create an array?

Comment: @Marwan Updated my screenshot to better reflect what you're looking for.

Comment: @AGS You can always type a few letters first and greatly reduce the amount of results... And for the times when you want to see every method available quickly, you can also do that too.

Comment: For me to get this to work, I had to clone the repo instead of using the package control manager.  The code completion would not work with the automatic package install.  So instead I cloned the plugin using git into my mac sublime packages directory (which I found here .../Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages), and then cloned the repo: git clone git://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel.git -- It works!!

Comment: @firecape Yeah, I ran into the same install problems hence the note at the bottom of the answer. Although, I guess it's not a 'temporary install bug' if nearly 2 years later it still hasn't been fixed.