# Sublime3, ruby programming, autocomplete - show a class' methods (like java, actually)

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, sublimetext3

I am new to Sublime and to Ruby. I have been developing Java for 10+ years, and what I miss, is: autocomplete, in the meaning of:
using: Sublime3 (ok if had to switch to 2 to get this option) + Rails.
issue: I want: I type: "MyClass. [DOT]" say: I type the dot 
and then: a list of methods of this class are displayed. These methods that are defined by default (as of heritage), and those that I have defined, in the class definition.
I am aware of the 'duck-typing' style, such: also these methods, that this object itself is able to use, would be a plus.
While, I would be happy with the first two (heritage and self.methods).

Yes I am aware that the Ruby-community is sort of pure coding; I like it also, and I also appreciate an editor that helps.

I have read through answers in GITHUB, and I could not figure out if that is existing or not .. it seems, the Ruby-people do not understand this Java-coding idea.

Thank you for any link or answer.

Comment: This is not very practical. A string object has 168 methods. `Object.new.methods.size` (an "empty" object) counts 56 methods. You could try `MyClass.` followed by two tabs in irb to get a feel.

Comment: See also this question which answers a similar question but directly answers your Sublime question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17203004/1574942

RubyMine is great but not Sublime Text and not free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime is a text editor, is not an IDE. In the Java world you are likely used to write your code with IDE (such as Netbeans, Eclipse, Intellij IDEA), I have never seen Java developers using a pure text editor.

There are some IDE for Ruby. However, the highly dynamic and loosely typed nature of Ruby makes it really hard to provide an accurate IntelliSense code completion. Both the assumption that the Ruby community pretends to be pure, or Ruby-people do not understand Java-coding idea are simply wrong. Several Ruby developers approached the language from Java, therefore they are perfectly aware of how the Java world works.

If you feel more comfortable with an IDE, try to search for a Ruby one. [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) is a great product, and if you come from Java world you may already be familiar with Intellij IDEA. There are also [plugins for Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/features/ruby/index.html) and [Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ruby-dltk), but the runtime evaluation capabilities of RubyMine are far superior and it's also the most up-to-date.

Most of text editors, such as TextMate, Sublime Text, Atom, etc understands Ruby and provide Ruby syntax highlighting and additional features, some of them even autocompletion, but IDE-level features as you would expect from the Java world.

Comment: Thank you both! especially @Simone Carletti, that was very clear - could not find such clear answer about this topic before.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete is possible in Sublime - there are several packages for Python, including the excellent [`Anaconda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda) plugin. Coverage for Ruby isn't quite as deep, but I did find [`SublimeRsense`](https://github.com/rsense/SublimeRsense) which may fit your needs. The README implies that it's for Atom, but I think that's just left over from another repo. I'm not a Rubyist, so I didn't install it, but the directions looked pretty straightforward.

That being said, depending on your personal preferences and knowledge, an IDE may work better for you. Of course, it'll take up a lot more room on your HD and in memory, and may get in your way at times, but with that comes many more features that you won't find in a text editor, even one as advanced as Sublime. Try them both out, and use what works for you. Personally, I prefer Sublime over IDEs, as I find many of their "features" annoying, but you'll have to see what best matches your style and needs.